# Prototype and jQuery UI interference

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, magento, prototypejs

Ok so I've been researching this for a while and reordered my javascript files who knows how many times. I do know Prototype and jQuery do not work well with eachother. However, my jQuery is working, but my jQuery UI functions are not.

I'm listing my js files in this order:
- prototype.js
- jquery.js
- jquery-ui.js
- jquery-noconflict.js

My jQuery no conflict file looks like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Ok all of that junk is in the  tags. Later on in a page, I'm doing this:

```
<div class="product_tabs clearfix">
    <ul>
        <?php if ($_description): ?> <li><a href="#tabs-1"><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></a></li> <?php endif; ?>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Review</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tags</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="std clearfix">
        <?php if ($_description): ?> <div id="tabs-1"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description') ?></div> <?php endif; ?>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span5"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_form') ?></div>
                <div class="span4"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('reviews') ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_tag_list') ?></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.product_tabs').tabs();
    });
</script>
```

And this is broken.. However, my main.js file that is called BEFORE my noconflict file, but after my js and prototype files works with my drop down navigation using the same ready() as the function above works.

However, I move that tabs() function into the main.js file and it still doesn't work while erasing it from the page. Does anyone have any solution to this?

I erased the noconflict on the page that was using the tabs() function and it works fine, but IE8 and below, it does not. So that wasn't a valuable solution... That was the only one I could think of.

And I have to keep prototype because I'm using the Magento CMS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use $ for Prototype functions and jQuery for jQuery's, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.product_tabs').tabs();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention. I've tried that as well and it still doesn't function right. The jQuery UI classes are added to the tabs, but the functionality isn't there..
EDIT - Wait... it's working. o.o My CSS just isn't being applied. xD Wow... I was like well they didn't look like how they looked before so it doesn't even work without even testing. GEEZ THANKS... o.o I'm so blind. I tried that and was too stubborn to check.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to load jQuery at very top i.e. before prototype and write `jQuery.noconflict()` at the end of your jquery file. Then initialize your jQuery code with `jQuery(document).ready(function($){...});`.